Ubuntu Server 22.04 - Problem with umask value
I would like to update the default value of umask to 775 (002).
I updated the value in the file etc/login.defs (I found this tip in some online guides)
login.defs
but when I type umask from the command line, the system still returns the default value (022 and not 002). Where am I going wrong?
umask command from the command line
